# SSRS: One filter for two fields

Tags: reporting-services, filter

I am trying to filter two fields with one parameter, with the "OR" condition.  Where the parameter is prompting a user to enter search text, to see if either field contains that text.  I have tried doing:

Expression:

```
=(Fields!Part_Number.Value Or Fields!Part_Description.Value)
```

But it errors out.  The last half of it, I believe I have right, because if I just filtered against one field its works:

Expression:

```
=Fields!Part_Number.Value
```

Operator = Like

Value:

```
="*" + Parameters!SearchText.Value + "*"
```

Now I wish I could just change the expression to filter on both fields.  I tired to make a filter for each expression, but then it behaves like "AND" instead of "OR" so that both the fields have to contain the search text, whereas I only need one of the fields to contain the text.  Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would put the entire comparison into the Expression, and change the Operator to =, the Type to Boolean and the Value to True.

So the full Expression would be something like:

`= Fields!Part_Number.Value Like "*" + Parameters!SearchText.Value + "*"
Or Fields!Part_Description.Value Like "*" + Parameters!SearchText.Value + "*"`